# SQL query to check if there are records in the database of 6 consecutive 'Sundays'

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to build a query to check if there are records in the database of 6 consecutive 'Sundays'

```
SELECT DISTINCT ST1.DATAPU, ST1.NUMCAD, TO_CHAR(ST1.DATAPU, 'DAY') AS DIA
  FROM SENIOR.R066SIT ST1
 WHERE ST1.DATAPU BETWEEN '01/01/22' AND '23/11/22'
   AND ST1.NUMCAD = 10
   AND TO_CHAR(ST1.DATAPU, 'FMDAY') = 'DOMINGO' -->which is SUNDAY in English
 ORDER BY ST1.DATAPU ASC
```

With this query above, I get the result of the records as shown in the image below

[image]

Comment: Could you please describe what is considered as 'consecutive`?

Comment: All rows you got are Sundays (and they follow one after another so - yes, they are *consecutive*), so ... what is the question, exactly?

Comment: All lines are Sunday, yes. However, it will not necessarily be the Sunday of the 1st and after the 8th (this is a consecutive Sunday). If it's for example Sunday the 1st, and then the 15th, I'm not interested in consultation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row pattern analysis:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT DISTINCT
         TRUNC(DATAPU) AS datapu,
         NUMCAD,
         TO_CHAR(DATAPU,'DAY') AS DIA
  FROM   SENIOR.R066SIT
  WHERE  DATAPU BETWEEN DATE '2022-01-01' AND DATE '2022-11-23'
  AND    NUMCAD = 10
  AND    TRUNC(DATAPU) - TRUNC(DATAPU, 'IW') = 6 -- Sunday
)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY datapu
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (first_week consecutive_week{5,})
  DEFINE
    consecutive_week AS PREV(datapu) + INTERVAL '7' DAY = datapu
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE senior.r066sit(numcad, datapu) AS
SELECT 10, DATE '2022-01-01' + LEVEL - 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5*7
UNION ALL
SELECT 10, DATE '2022-04-01' + LEVEL - 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7*7
UNION ALL
SELECT 10, DATE '2022-08-01' + LEVEL - 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7*7;
```

Outputs:

| DATAPU | NUMCAD | DIA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-03 00:00:00 | 10 | SUNDAY |
| 2022-04-10 00:00:00 | 10 | SUNDAY |
| 2022-04-17 00:00:00 | 10 | SUNDAY |
| 2022-04-24 00:00:00 | 10 | SUNDAY |
| 2022-05-01 00:00:00 | 10 | SUNDAY |
| 2022-05-08 00:00:00 | 10 | SUNDAY |
| 2022-05-15 00:00:00 | 10 | SUNDAY |
| 2022-08-07 00:00:00 | 10 | SUNDAY |
| 2022-08-14 00:00:00 | 10 | SUNDAY |
| 2022-08-21 00:00:00 | 10 | SUNDAY |
| 2022-08-28 00:00:00 | 10 | SUNDAY |
| 2022-09-04 00:00:00 | 10 | SUNDAY |
| 2022-09-11 00:00:00 | 10 | SUNDAY |
| 2022-09-18 00:00:00 | 10 | SUNDAY |

---

Before Oracle 12, you can use multiple analytic functions in nested sub-queries:

```sql
SELECT datapu, numcad,
       TO_CHAR(datapu, 'fmDAY') AS dia
FROM   (
  SELECT datapu, numcad,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY grp) AS grp_size
  FROM   (  
    SELECT datapu, numcad,
           SUM(consecutive) OVER (ORDER BY datapu) AS grp
    FROM   (
      SELECT datapu, numcad,
             CASE datapu - LAG(datapu) OVER (ORDER BY datapu)
             WHEN 7
             THEN 0
             ELSE 1
             END AS consecutive
      FROM   (
        SELECT DISTINCT
               TRUNC(DATAPU) AS datapu,
               NUMCAD
        FROM   SENIOR.R066SIT
        WHERE  DATAPU BETWEEN DATE '2022-01-01' AND DATE '2022-11-23'
        AND    NUMCAD = 10
        AND    TRUNC(DATAPU) - TRUNC(DATAPU, 'IW') = 6 -- Sunday
      )
    )
  )
)
WHERE  grp_size >= 6;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4nFTPcxT)

Comment: I tried to run your SELECT but got the error below

00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

*Cause:    

*Action:
Error in line: 12 Column: 16

Comment: @Brandalize It works perfectly for me in the fiddle. I am guessing that you are not using Oracle 12 or later (which is mentioned in the first words of the answer) and you have not tagged a specific Oracle version in the question.

Comment: Sorry. It's the first time I'm working with Oracle, I didn't know that the version could cause so much impact. In fact, I don't even know where I see my version

Comment: @Brandalize `SELECT * FROM V$VERSION`. I've updated with a query that should run on versions before Oracle 12 (provided they support analytic queries).

Comment: Thank you for your help! I checked the version and apparently I'm on 11.2. With your updated code I managed to solve the problem